# social.framework ios5

Tags: ios

When I run my app with social framework for facebook on ios5 it crashes, and I can understand that. Is there a way to import it just if the device is ios6?

I tried this, where ver_float is the ios version:

```
if (ver_float >= 6.0) {
    #import <Social/Social.h>
}
```

But the app fails to run if I remove the #import  from the top of the code page.

Comment: After setting the framework to optional as Alessandro has pointed out correctly, you should do something like the following to check for the availability of the methods you want to use in iOS6 only:
if ([SLComposeViewController instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(isAvailableForServiceType)] != nil) ... and  if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just make sure you set the Social.framework as optional under Build Phases.